# Время в PostgreSQL

Tags: время, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте.

Вот интересует след. вопрос:

Как в PostgreSQL сделать так, чтобы время указывало на текущий часовой пояс (а то я как бы нахожусь в зоне +3 часа) но когда создаю пост..

У меня created_at (столбец) указывает на время +0 часов.

Создаю пост в 11 вечера, а указывает на 9 вечера.

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справился с заданным вопросом через

```
    before_filter :set_timezone

    def set_timezone  
     min = request.cookies['time_zone'].to_i
     Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[min]
    end

application.js
application_controller

    function SetTimeZone() {
        var today = new Date();
        var offset = -(today.getTimezoneOffset()/60);
        $.cookie('time_zone', offset);
    }
SetTimeZone();
```

Answer (score 3):

Хранить всё равно как. Либо сохранять с таймзоной сервера, либо с GMT+0, либо с GMT+0 и не писать вообще в БД зону (главное не сохранять с пользовательской таймзоной, ибо она у всех пользователей разная, и придётся ещё приплетать автора поста к запросу). Выводить же даты нужно так:

```
Time.zone.at(post.created_at)
```

Ещё неплохо учитывать то, что если пользователь вводит у вас где-то время вручную, то его надо обратно преобразовывать из пользовательской таймзоны в серверную.

Answer (score 2):

В PostgreSQL есть два разных типа для хранения момента времени - "timestamp with time zone" и "timestamp without time zone". По умолчанию (т.е. когда написано просто "timestamp") используется второй - без часового пояса. Видимо, проблема именно в этом.

Comment: а что конкретно в миграции писать? вот у меня есть -> "t.timestamps" (которая добавит cteated_at и updated_at.

Comment: Это надо спросить у знатоков "рельсы". Я не знаю.